# Memorization for Rule + ReplaceRepeated?

Tags: evaluation, algorithm, memoization

### Question

When build packages of noncummutative algebras I met the choice:

1. `Rule` + `ReplaceRepeated`
2. `SetDelayed/TagSetDelayed`
3. `SetDelayed/TagSetDelayed` + memorization

and I need some hybrid of 1 and 3 like

4. `Rule` + `ReplaceRepeated` + memorization

so that some part of the intermediate results of `//.rule` will be stored into `rule`.

**Q: why not using `SetDelayed/TagSetDelayed` + memorization?**

1. `TagSetDelayed` only deal with shallow levels. Simpler rules like `f[expr1_]+f[expr2_]:>expr` can be translated into `f/:f[expr1_]+f[expr2_]:=expr`, but there are more complicated rules in which the levels of relevant symbols are too deep.
2. Different rules from different algebras should be isolated. For example, the same symbol `f` appears in two lists of rules `rule1` and `rule2`, and the evaluation can be easily controlled as,

```
expr//.rule1
expr//.rule2
```

### Motivated example and benchmark

The algebraic relations are equivalently translated into a list of rules. Here is an example from Y system (irrelevant to this question, put here just for concreteness),

```
ruleY={
funY1[j_,u_,n_]/;j<=0||j>=n+1:>0,
funY1[j_,u_,n_]/;u>=2:>(funY1[j-1,u-1,n]+1)(1+funY1[j+1,u-1,n])/funY1[j,u-2,n]
};
```

and if checking the relation
$$Y(n-j+1,u,n)=Y(j,u+n+3,n)$$
we just set `{j,n,u}=...` and

```
funY1[n-j+1,u,n]-funY1[j,u+n+3,n]//.ruleY
```

Here is the benchmark of method 1,2 and 3.

- `f1`: `Rule` + `ReplaceRepeated`
- `f1nest`: `Rule` + `ReplaceAll` + `FixedPoint`
- `f2`: `SetDelayed/TagSetDelayed`
- `f2m`: `SetDelayed/TagSetDelayed` + memorization

[image]

`SetDelayed/TagSetDelayed` are faster than `Rule` + `ReplaceRepeated` by a constant multiple. Memorization is the best as expected.

The relevant codes:

```
ruleY={
funY1[j_,u_,n_]/;j<=0||j>=n+1:>0,
funY1[j_,u_,n_]/;u>=2:>(funY1[j-1,u-1,n]+1)(1+funY1[j+1,u-1,n])/funY1[j,u-2,n]
};

funY2[j_,u_,n_]/;j<=0||j>=n+1:=0;
funY2[j_,u_,n_]/;u>=2:=(funY2[j-1,u-1,n]+1)(1+funY2[j+1,u-1,n])/funY2[j,u-2,n];

funY2m[j_,u_,n_]/;j<=0||j>=n+1:=funY2m[j,u,n]=0;
funY2m[j_,u_,n_]/;u>=2:=funY2m[j,u,n]=(funY2m[j-1,u-1,n]+1)(1+funY2m[j+1,u-1,n])/funY2m[j,u-2,n];

expr[n_][fun_]:=Module[{j=1,u=0},fun[n-j+1,u,n]-fun[j,u+n+3,n]]

functionList[1]={f1,f1nest,f2,f2m};

With[{$$expr=(expr[n$][funY1])},
    f1[n_]:=$$expr//.ruleY
]
With[{$$expr=(expr[n$][funY1])},
    f1nest[n_]:=FixedPoint[ReplaceAll[#,ruleY]&,$$expr]
]
f2[n_]:=Evaluate@expr[n]@funY2
f2m[n_]:=Evaluate@expr[n]@funY2m

Clear[GeneralUtilities`Benchmarking`PackagePrivate`$TimingCaches]
benchmark[1]=Benchmark[functionList[1],#&,Range[10]];

ListLogPlot[benchmark[1],Joined->True,PlotLabels->functionList[1],PlotMarkers->Automatic,ImageSize->Full]
```

Comment: You could use a helper function on the right side of the replacement rule that does the memoization, somerhing like `expr:(f[_]+f[_]):>rule1[expr]`, `rule1[expr:(f[expr1_]+f[expr2_])]:=rule1[expr]=...`

Comment: @LukasLang Thx and sorry for the late reply. I was working on other problems these days. I'll try your ideas.